# C# dll previewing crystal report

Tags: c#, dll, crystal-reports

I'm trying to generate a form containing a crystal report viewer from a dll 
but I got the error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" when I try to compile the dll.

Any solution to solve this problem? Many thanks.

```
ReportDocument tempCover = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
tempCover.Load(exepath+"\\ImageStatementCoverPage.rpt");
CrystalReportViewer tempViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
tempViewer.ReportSource = tempCover;
tempViewer.Show;
```

Comment: What line did this happen on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show is a function:

try `tempViewer.Show();`

Comment: The original problem was a compiler error, right?  That is fixed.  Diagnose and experiment as much as you can (verify there is data and the connection is open, all the setting and parameters are correct, etc).   If you can't get it working after a few hours, THEN post another question.